# Issue around Mapped Tuple Types with type inference

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I'm trying to wrap my head around a problem concerning [mapped tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html).
They appear to work when I explicitly define a type to map, but when the type to map is inferred via a generic, the type-system appears to not work correctly.

```
class Boxed<T> {
  constructor(private arg: T){ }
}
type MapToRaw<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Boxed<infer E> ? E : never };

// WORKS AS EXPECTED
let val: MapToRaw<[Boxed<number>, Boxed<string>]>;
// 'val' is of type [number, string]

// DOESN'T WORK AS EXPECTED
let fn = <X extends Boxed<any>[]>(arg: X) => null as any as MapToRaw<X>;
let res = fn([new Boxed(0), new Boxed('')]);
// 'res' is of type (string | number)[]
```

I actually don't think there is a way to do this without doing the following:

```
let fn = <X extends Boxed<any>[]>(...arg: X) => null as any as MapToRaw<X>;
let res = fn(new Boxed(0), new Boxed(''));
// 'res ' is of type [number, string]
```

but in my case, I'd prefer to pass in an array rather than variadic arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hint to the compiler that `B` should be a tuple, not just a simple array. You can do this with a type constraint of `[T] | T[]`:

```
class Boxed<T> {
  constructor(private arg: T){ }
}
type MapToRaw<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Boxed<infer E> ? E : never };

let fn = <X extends [Boxed<any>] | Boxed<any>[]>(arg: X) => null! as MapToRaw<X>;
let res = fn([new Boxed(0), new Boxed('')]);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD2APApgEwDwBUB80DeAsAFDTTDwB2EALgE4Cuw18tAFAA60CWAbmNcmhhaAcwBc0TAEo80AL7EFRagE92ggLJh2meACUwAdyy4AvPmgBtANLQuFaAGtkK+ADNJAXQmYbn6MiIAhSoMAgoGPZuyLTQAKK4APzx0BIUyDwx8gDcxMQgyNTQbg7m6AAaAUHIITCW4WjoYBQq2P4APnBIjc2tlp7YrMLi0OVS0Ka4FPQgIACEQjBaOvpGFdi5RAVFtMgw5iWslumGXRGsAAxSADTQJ2dorADkT1KeUptAA)